# How do i rotate rigged character bone in Unreal Engine outliner?

Tags: game-engine, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am new to Unreal Engine, I want to know is there any way to rotate rigged character bone in Unreal Engine outliner like what we do in Unity hierarchy? I tried too many ways but i can't find any solution for this.[Sample Image] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4aGa.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.